# Diferencia entre Modelo y Controlador Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dudas sobre como se usa un Modelo y un Controlador en Laravel 8

Al ejecutar el comando `php artisan make:controller example` me crea un modelo `Example` y un controlador `ExampleController`

Donde se crea la lógica supongo que es dentro del Controller, pero no se exactamente para que debo utilizar cada uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te refieres a que no sabes para que sirve el modelo y el controlador?
Pues veras, yo también uso Laravel, tratare de resumirtelo. En el modelo suelo poner el nombre los campos de la tabla (migración), su relación con otras tablas, y hasta algunas funcionalidades. Los modelos son para interactuar con nuestra base de datos, ejemplo sencillo:

```
<?php
            
namespace App\Models;
            
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;      
            
class Rol extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'roles';
            
   protected $fillable = [
    'nombre', 'descripcion', 'usuario_id'
   ];
        
   public function usuario()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Usuario');
   }
        
   public function usuarioRol()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UsuarioRol','rol_id');
   }
}
```

El en el controlador usualmente van funciones importantes, también conecta con las plantillas blade (si tienes), se pueden hacer reglas de validación (aunque para mi es mejor hacerlo en un archivo request), se pueden hacer las funcionalidades de guardar, actualizar, borrar, etc. Un controlador no es más que una clase de PHP, son un mecanismo que permite agrupar la lógica de peticiones HTTP relacionadas. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rol;

class RolController extends Controller
{   
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //consulta los roles
        $roles  = Rol::all();

        //redirecciona a la vista index de la carpeta roles
        return view('roles.index', compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //redirecciona a la carpeta roles al archivo create
        return view('roles.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            nombre => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/u',
            descripcion => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/u',
        ],[
            'nombre.required' => 'El campo nombre es obligatorio',
            'descripcion.required' => 'El campo descripcion es obligatorio',
        ]);

        $data[nombre] = $request->nombre; 
        $data[descripcion] = $request->descripcion; 

        Rol::create($data);
   
        return redirect('/admin/roles')->with('success', MESSAGE_SAVE_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

No se si me pude explicar de manera sencilla pero si apenas estas empezando, usa San Google, Laravel es un framework muy popular, podras encontrar de todo. Buena suerte!